# Euler's Formula, from Needham's Visual Complex Analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm having trouble understanding this passage.

> **12** Geometry and Comples Arithmetic
>
> [image]
>
> Figure $[8]$
>
> Since we now know that $|Z(t)|$ remains equal to $1$ throughout the motion, it follows that the particle's speed $|V(t)|$ also remains equal to $1$. Thus after time $t=\theta$ the partial will have travelled a distance $\theta$ round the unit circle, and so the angle of $Z(\theta)=e^{i\theta}$ will be $\theta$. This is the geometric statement of Euler's formula.

I don't understand the last paragraph.  Why is it that $|Z(t)|$ remains equal to 1 throughout the motion?

Comment: I don't see $|z(t)|$ anywhere. Edit: you mean in the third page?

Answer (score 2):

I disagree with [@MarkFantini](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/88052/mark-fantini)'s [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/871548).

In this section ($\S$1.II.2 *Moving Particle Argument*), Needham is giving a heuristic argument in support of the fact that $e^{i \theta} = \cos \theta + i \sin \theta$. He has *not* defined $e^{i \theta}$ to be $\cos \theta + i \sin \theta$, and in fact he argues that doing so is "a low blow to Euler, reducing one of his greatest achievements to a mere tautology" ($\S$1.II.1 *Introduction*, page 10).

Instead, what Needham is arguing in $\S$1.II.2 is that if we suppose that it makes sense to talk about $e^{it}$, then a natural property we would want it to have is $\frac{d}{dt}e^{it} = i e^{it}$ (eq. (11) on page 11), analogous to the known property of the real exponential function, namely $\frac{d}{dx} e^{kx} = k e^{kx}$ for any real $k$.

Now, visualizing the function $t \mapsto e^{it}$ as describing the motion of a moving particle in the plane, the quantity $\frac{d}{dt} e^{it}$ is then the velocity of the particle. We know that multiplication by $i$ corresponds to a rotation of the plane by $\pi/2$ radians in the counter-clockwise direction. So, the position and velocity vectors are at right angles to each other at every point. From this, and the fact that at $t = 0$ the particle is at $e^0 = 1$, one can deduce that the particle is just moving around the unit circle.

Hence, $\lvert e^{it} \rvert = 1$ for all $t$.

Answer (score 0):

He mentions that $Z(t) = e^{it}.$ You have $$|Z(t)| = |e^{it}| = \sqrt{\cos^2(t) + \sin^2(t)} = 1.$$

Comment: Oh thank you.  Jebus math is hard.

Comment: I have written a competing [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3969929) because here Needham is trying to provide a heuristic argument for why $e^{i t} = \cos t + i \sin t$, so he does not (and cannot) use $e^{it} = \cos t + i \sin t$ to deduce that $\lvert e^{it} \rvert = 1$.