# Is there a geometric proof of the de Moivre's formula?

Tags: complex-numbers

I am trying to understand (intuitively) this formula here:
$$e^{ic} = cos (c) + i.sin (c)$$

I understand the infinite sum (traditional) approach [1](https://www.math.toronto.edu/mathnet/questionCorner/complexexp.html), but I am looking for something more geometric, maybe because of the involvement of the trig functions. I found another approach [2](https://www.math.toronto.edu/mathnet/questionCorner/epii.html) which uses the fact that (assuming $f(x)=e^{ix}$):
$$f'(x)=i.e^{ix}=i(g(x)+i.h(x))=i.g(x)-h(x) $$

Since the pair of functions $g$ and $h$ for which $h' = g$ and $g' = -h$ happen to be sine and cosine, we get the proof.

I know that exponentiation involving imaginary numbers are more easily dealt with using the power series, but is there a more visual approach to this?

Comment: To better understand your question: Are you happy with the fact that $e^{it}$ traces the unit circle or is that the main point you are struggling with?

Comment: The question ['Euler's Formula, from Needham's Visual Complex Analysis"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/871535/409) shows a geometric representation of the identity. A GeoGebra project linked from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1839484/409) gives a dynamic form of the illustration. I believe there are other instances scattered about Math.SE.

Comment: @Klaus Yes, I understand that. And I know this question is pretty trivial- sorry for that...

Comment: @Blue Thank you, I found my answer!

Comment: [Here is the best visual explanation I have seen.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v0YEaeIClKY&t=7s)

Answer (score 1):

Complex numbers admit the matrix representation $x+yi=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
x & -y\\
y & x
\end{array}\right)$. They can then be seen as a generalization of $2\times2$ rotation matrices that also including scaling. Writing rotation matrices as something exponentiated then just means anticlockwise rotations by $\theta,\,\phi$ compose to an anticlockwise rotation by $\theta+\phi$. Why the base is $e^{i}$ is the hard part, which I think needs Taylor series, albeit seen again in terms of matrices.